# Strange behavior when truncating while using MathJax

Tags: javascript, mathjax

I have MathJax implemented for a website and what I am trying to implement is shortening the text area to a certain length and have it be clickable and then load more on click. MathJax loads the truncated text just fine, but when I click the text to expand it to the entire paragraph, MathJax appends the initial shortened math to the end of the newly rendered entire paragraph. Does anyone have any experience with this? I'm assuming it is occurring because the truncated text is still on the queue and so it still prints it after the entire text is loaded, but I cant seem to figure out how to clear the queue shortened text from the queue to get it to work properly. Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the basics of my code:

```
var showOnClick = function() {
        ctrl.showAll(!ctrl.showAll());
};

MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset', MathJax.Hub]);
return m('p.readable.pointer', {onclick: showOnClick},
          ctrl.showAll() ? result.description : description_truncated);
```

Comment: I suppose that the text area is not a part of MathJax... did you write the onclick mechanics yourself? Can you post a code sample in your question?

Comment: sure thing, just updated @Igor

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with the showAll function in your controller, so I answered as I thought it should work from your description.

Comment: @Igor Great, thank you! I am trying to apply your code to my situation. It looks like it will be just what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the main reason is that you already have all those spans that contain the formula parts and when you add the text, the engine tries to take all the contents of your text field as a source and reformat it. Since the spans don't look like the math source, it discards them (it is just a guess, but looks like it works this way).

My solution: instead of appending some text directly, add a new span and only regenerate the formula in this span. Be careful: if the text you are adding is cut like this it won't work: ["my super formula: $x \subset ", "\mathbb{R}$."].

So, here's my simplified example (note that I refresh the span with the id "txt2"):

```js
<head>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});

  function addText() {
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML += '<span id=txt2> ...adding new formula: $x\\subseteq X$</span>';
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,"txt2"]);
  }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" async
  src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML">
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id=txt>$1\neq 0$</div>
  <input type=button onclick="addText()" value="Do it"/>
</body>
```

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 0):

Your original post doesn't show how you were adding the additional text to the paragraph, but if it was using `innerHTML += ...` like in your answer, then that was probably the source of your duplicate math.  By doing this, you are deleting the current DOM and replacing it with a new one, copied from the old one, but not identical to it.  In particular, you lose the values that MathJax has stored with the old DOM that record what has been processed, and so when you asked MathJax to typeset the page again, it looked like all the math was new so it was typeset again, introducing a second copy of the typeset math into the document.

While your current version does avoid the duplication, it still has lost all the connections from the copied DOM to MathJax.  For example, the contextual menu will no longer work on the older math expressions, since the code that handles that hasn't been copied by setting `innerHTML`.  So this is not a good way to proceed.

Instead, you might try

```
document.getElementById('txt')
        .appendChild(document.createTextNode('...adding new formula: $x\\subseteq X$'));
```

which will not alter the existing DOM, but simply add a new text node.  Then you can typeset the page again without getting duplication.